The odata.type in the URI of Redfish is inconsistent with the version obtained from JsonSchemas
Should the @odata.type in /redfish/v1/AccountService/Accounts/root and the $id version information in /redfish/v1/JsonSchemas/ManagerAccount/ManagerAccount.json be the same?
I found that they are different in OpenBMC. If they are allowed to be different, what do these two pieces of data represent?
Execution of /redfish/v1/AccountService/Accounts/root:
{ "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/AccountService/Accounts/root", 
  "@odata.type": "#ManagerAccount.v1_4_0.ManagerAccount", 
  "AccountTypes": [ "IPMI", "Redfish", "WebUI", "HostConsole", "ManagerConsole" ],
 .............

Execution of /redfish/v1/JsonSchemas/ManagerAccount/ManagerAccount.json:
{
 "$id": "http://redfish.dmtf.org/schemas/v1/ManagerAccount.v1_9_0.json",
 "$ref": "#/definitions/ManagerAccount",
 "$schema": "http://redfish.dmtf.org/schemas/v1/redfish-schema-v1.json",
 "copyright": "Copyright 2014-2022 DMTF. For the full DMTF copyright policy, see http://www.dmtf.org/about/policies/copyright",
 "definitions": {
 .............

